# How would I set up access to multiple Nodes with a single Service in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service, kubernetes-networking

I am trying to set up access to Pods on multiple Nodes with a single Service yaml. The Pods all have the same label (say, `label:app`), but are distributed across several Nodes, instead of on a single Node.

As far as I know, I can set up a Service to forward access to a Pod through a NodePort, like:

```
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    label: app
  ports:
    targetPort: 5000
    nodePort: 30000
```

where accessing port 30000 on a node forwards to port 5000 on the pod.

If I have pods on multiple nodes, is there a way a client can access a single endpoint, e.g. the Service itself, to get any pod in round-robin? Or does a client need to access a set of pods on a specific node, using that node's IP, as in `xx.xx.xx.xx:30000`?

Comment: "Or does a client need to access a set of pods [...]"

Can you please clarify if the client is internal or external to the kubernetes cluster?

Comment: The client is external to the cluster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) is an undeniably recommended solution (especially in cloud environment), it's worth mentioning that [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) also has **load balancing capabilities**.

The fact that you're accessing your `NodePort` Service on a particular node doesn't mean that you are able to access this way only `Pods` that have been scheduled on that particular node.

As you can read in `NodePort` Service [specification](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport):

> Each node proxies that port (the same port number on every Node)
> into your `Service`.

So by accessing port `30080` on one particular node your request is not going directly to some random `Pod`, scheduled on that node. It is proxied to the `Service` object which is an abstraction that spans across all nodes. And this is probably the key point here as your `NodePort` Service isn't tied in any way to the node, IP of which you use to access your pods.

Therefore `NodePort` Service is able to route client requests to all pods across the cluster using simple **round robin algorithm**.

You can verify it easily using the following `Deployment`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: init-myservice
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        command: ['sh', '-c', "echo $MY_NODE_NAME > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html"]
        env:
        - name: MY_NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
          name: cache-volume
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
          name: cache-volume
      volumes:
      - name: cache-volume
        emptyDir: {}
```

This will allow you to test to which node your http request is going to. You may additionally need to scale a bit this `Deployment` to make sure that all nodes are used:

```
kubectl scale deployment nginx-deployment --replicas=9
```

Then verify that your pods are scheduled on different nodes:

```
kubectl get pods -o wide
```

List all your nodes:

```
kubectl get nodes -o wide
```

and pick the IP address of a node that you want to use to access your pods.

Now you can expose the `Deployment` by running:

```
kubectl expose deployment nginx-deployment --type NodePort --port 80 --target-port 80
```

or if you want to specify the port number by yourself e.g. as `30080`, apply the following `NodePort` Service definition as `kubectl expose` doesn't allow you to specify the exact `nodePort` value:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30080
```

Then try to access your pods exposed via `NodePort` Service using IP of the previously chosen node. You may need to try both normal and private/incognito modes or even different browser (simple refresh may not work) but eventually you will see that different requests land on pods scheduled on different nodes.

Keep in mind that if you decide to use `NodePort` you won't be able to use **well known ports**. Actually it might be even feasible as you may change the default port range (`30000-32767`) to something like `1-1024` in [kube-apiserver](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/) configuration by using `--service-node-port-range` option but its not recommended as it might lead to some unexpected issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for single entry point to your application service and it is running in cloud infrastructure then you can use [Load balancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) service (instead of node port) which will assign a external IP for your service which can be used to access your service from external system.

```
spec:
  ports:
    - name: httpsPort
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 443
  selector:
    label: app
  type: LoadBalancer
```

If you are having multiple service within same cluster which needs to be accessed from external system then you can use [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/).

Thanks
Kiruba